# Python 3.4 graphviz issue

Tags: python, path, graphviz

I have to run below code on Jupyter notebook.

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
print(dot.source) 
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

i have to install graphviz beforehand. after i installed graphviz 2.38 on windows 10. i did 'pip install graphviz'
and 'conda install graphviz' as well. but i get this error

"RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path"

What else should i do to make this error gone?

Answer (score 0):

Your python runtime is running with a PATH environment variable that does not include the path to graphviz.

You can confirm this by checking whether the following (py3) code:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

does list the directory where graphviz was installed. If it has not, modify your system PATH environment variable [1], or add the path to the graphviz binaries with the following command each time BEFORE running your python:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;this_would_be_the_path_to_your_graphiz_binaries_like_dot
```

[1] https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them